# Word VBA - Load part of doc into variable, and run .indexOf to search

Tags: vba, ms-word, string-formatting

Okay, I am a Javascript programmer and VBA is driving me insane - I know nothing about it and it is like pulling teeth to find simple documentation on the simplest thing.

I'm literally trying to run a little script to auto-format a document, partly based in content.

I want to grab the third line of document, or first 100 characters, I really don't care, and run the equivalent of `String().indexOf('foobar')` on it, to check if that part of the document contains a string.

I cannot for the life of me find how to:

a. Load text selection into a variable.
b. Run a sane semblance to `indexOf`.

Can someone please help? And maybe point me to a sane VBA documentation that is not Micrsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. Load text selection into a variable.

Identify a range (`Word.Range`) you want and get the `Text` property of that range.
For instance,

```
dim s as string
s = ThisDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text
```

---

> b. Run a sane semblance to indexOf.

Is [`InStr`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/HV080608419.aspx) no good?

```
msgbox InStr(s, "foobar")
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you use it.

Comment: `If hasFoobar > 0 Then <linebreak> doStuff <linebreak> End If`